# What's the point using String.ToCharArray if a string is a char array itself?

Tags: c#

```
string s = "string";
Console.WriteLine(s[1]); // returns t

char[] chars = s.ToCharArray();
Console.WriteLine(chars[1]); // also returns t
```

so what is the point in this method?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A string is *not* a char array. You are confusing the fact that it has an indexer returning char with it being a char array.

Answer (score 5):

Just because you can write `s[1]` doesn't mean that a string **is** a char array, it meerely means `string` has an **indexer** that returns a `char`. The fact that indexers are accessed with the same syntax as array member access is a C# language feature.

Answer (score 3):

System.String isn't a character array.
If you need a character array (e.g. to pass as an argument to a method that's expecting one), you will need to do this conversion.